# What reflects UV radiation more: stratus clouds or cumulus clouds?

Tags: clouds, atmospheric-radiation

Interested in this since I sometimes look down on the clouds in the plane, and wonder if some of the reflected UV-A radiation might damage my eyes.

Comment: The type of cloud provided in the question is misleading. For exemple, when you say cumulus, you speak about cumulonimbus, stratucumulus, altocumulus or cirrocumulus? Moreover, there are different type of stratus cloud. Each of them will have a different relationship with respect to reflection of UV radiation. This kind of precision is needed to answer your question.

Comment: @Balinus -Late to comment on this but totally agree with your comment

Comment: @Balinus -i agree with you. There are a lot of different type of cumulus and stratus clouds with all other characteristics. It is an interesting question though

Comment: the type of uv light is important for its properties,is the question about UV-A only.shorter wavelenght UV never reaches as deep into the atmosphere as to where the clouds are,and the longest wavelenght UV is only scattered by clouds and not realy reflected.

Answer (score 1):

According to the below albedo rating diagram (percentage is reflection of incident radiation) cumulus cloud is the greater total spectrum reflector so it will reflect more UV that equivalent stratus formations.

[image]

Do note that water vapour does however absorb the vast majority of UV (≈100nm) that it intercepts as we can see in this diagram:[image]

So overall cloud UV reflectance will be quite low.

Comment: Can you clarify what's the y axis in the first figure?

Comment: @Gimelist Sure it's total reflection as a percentage of incoming radiation.

Comment: @Ash can you share the source of the figures please ?

Comment: @Ayoubayjx The first is from Wikipedia's albedo article the second one I'm not sure where I sourced it but it appears to have been compiled by Martin Chapman.